# Navigating to a new page with button class

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-onpressed

This is my buttons class. I want to use its on pressed function to navigate to another page.

```
class DigerButtonu extends StatelessWidget {
  final String butonyazisi;
  final IconData butoniconu;
  final Function butonfonksiyonu;
  const DigerButtonu(this.butonyazisi,this.butonfonksiyonu,this.butoniconu);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,right: 20),
      width: 50,
      height: 550,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0xFF15182D).withOpacity(0.4),
              blurRadius: 8,
              spreadRadius: 2,
              offset: Offset(4,4),
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 0.2,
          )
      ),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Icon(butoniconu, color: Colors.white,size: 22,),
            MyVerticalText(butonyazisi),
            Icon(butoniconu, color: Colors.white,size: 22,),
          ],
        ),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Color(0xFF15182D),
          onPrimary: Colors.white,
          onSurface: Colors.grey,
          //elevation: 0,
        ),
        onPressed: (){
          butonfonksiyonu;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when i try to use the code below, it says 'The argument type 'Future'can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Function' '. How can i use it?

```
DigerButtonu('AYARLAR',Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => clicker()), route),Icons.settings_rounded)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use lambdas for passing functions. Currently you pass the result of your method and not the method itself.
Here is your code with the corresponding lambda expression:

```
DigerButtonu('AYARLAR', () => Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => clicker()), route),Icons.settings_rounded)
```